# ¿Cómo encuentrar documento especifico dentro de colección que tiene varios objetos? Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Tengo por ahora esto guardado en una base de datos, estoy usando flask-pymongo y necesito encontrar en este caso el diccionario con titulo 'Presente Simple', ¿Cómo puedo hacer?

```
learn = [
    {'title': 'Verb Tenses', 
    'img':'public/img/couse01.jpg',
    'tenses':[{'title':'Presente Simple',
                'subtitle':'Acciones que realizamos cotidianamente',
                'img':'public/img/course01.jpg',
                'url':'/simple_present'}
            ],
    'subtitle': 'Tiempos Verbales que usamos en nuestras conversaciones'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

La consulta quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```js
db.collection.find({},{"title": "Presente Simple"})
```

Espero y esto te ayude